# How to separately plot the figures in one big single figure using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have just started learning `Python`, I am analyzing a data from `.csv` file and I want to separate figures, but I am getting all the plots in one graph and I am not able to separate the graphs. Please help!

```
n = 10
i=0
for i in range(0,n):
    inflammation = matplotlib.pyplot.plot(data[i,:40])#inflammation graph for patient 0
```

This is the image i got ,but I want separate graphs:

[image]

Comment: First call `matplotlib.pyplot.figure()` inside the loop, that creates a new figure.

Comment: You could also look into figure notebooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always take a look at using [`subplot()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=subplot#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot), which would work as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for n in range(1, 11):
    plt.subplot(2, 5, n)
    plt.plot(range(12))

plt.show()
```

This would display the following in a single figure:

[image: Ten subplots]

Answer (score 1):

Just use a new `figure()`

```
n = 10
i=0
for i in range(0,n):
    matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
    inflammation = matplotlib.pyplot.plot(data[i,:40]) #inflammation graph for patient 0
```

Each figure uses a lot of memory. So use it sparingly. Learn about `clf()` and `cla()` and `savefig()` if you have too many figures ...